# PHP file copy: permission denied

Tags: php, copy

I'm trying to copy a file from one web server to another within our company.
Someone else had a similar question here which was solved for them using the approach below.

However, when I try this I get the message "failed to open stream: Permission denied".
The default login for the IIS web service is "Local System".  Should I ask IT to assign a "network" login for this service, as they have suggested? Is there a better solution?

```
<?php

$from = "\\\\belqcdata01\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\productspecs\\certificate.pdf";
$to = "\\\\akudata01\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\productspecs\\certificate2.pdf";

if(!@copy($from, $to))
{
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
  echo "File copied to remote!";
}

?>
```

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: The script needs to be executed by a user with permissions to both directories. It's that simple.

Comment: @mboeckle What part of that question makes you think its in any way a *nix question, or anything to do with uploading file from a web page to the server??? Engage brain ... read question ... check brain still engaged ... write answer.

Comment: @mboeckle obviously it's a Windows server.

Comment: I see you're having to double your backslashes because you're using double quotes. If you use single quotes, you don't have to.